# Why I can't stop Progress Bar with Timer?

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar

I am doing a **TicTacToe Game**. I want to control every player move with progress bar. If game is end, progress bar must be stopped. If one player moved but the other do not move progress bar must increase or decrease. Here is my codes

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var activePlayer = 1 // 1 = noughts, 2 = crosses
var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
var gameActive = true
var timer = Timer()

@IBOutlet weak var btnPlayAgain: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!

@IBAction func btnPlayAgain(_ sender: AnyObject) {
```

UPDATE

```
self.view.viewWithTag(1000)?.isHidden = true
if self.view.viewWithTag(1000)?.isHidden == false {
     self.view.viewWithTag(1000)?.isHidden = true
}
```

UPDATE

```
progressBar.progress = 0.5

gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

activePlayer = 1
gameActive = true


gameOverLabel.isHidden = true
gameOverLabel.center = CGPoint(x: gameOverLabel.center.x - 500, y: gameOverLabel.center.y)

btnPlayAgain.isHidden = true
btnPlayAgain.center = CGPoint(x: btnPlayAgain.center.x - 500, y: btnPlayAgain.center.y)

var buttonToClear : UIButton

for i in 0..<9 {
    buttonToClear = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
    buttonToClear.setImage(nil, for: .normal)

    }

}
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var gameOverLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.6, target: self, selector: #selector(updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


if (gameState[sender.tag] == 0) && ( gameActive == true) {

    gameState[sender.tag] = activePlayer

if activePlayer == 1 {
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: .normal)

    activePlayer = 2
} else {
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
   activePlayer = 1
}

    for combination in winningCombinations {
        if (gameState[combination[0]] != 0 &&
            gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] &&
            gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]) {

            gameActive = false

            if (gameState[combination[0]] == 1)
            {
                gameOverLabel.text = "Noughts has won!"

            } else {
                gameOverLabel.text = "Crosses has won!"
            }

           endGame()
        }
    }
    if gameActive == true {

    gameActive = false

    for buttonState in gameState {
        if buttonState == 0 {
            gameActive = true
        }
    }
    if gameActive == false {

        gameOverLabel.text = "It's a draw!"
        endGame()
    }
}
}

}
```

How can I control the progress bar is it 1 or 0 ? If 1 or 0 gameLabel.text must be "Crosses or Noughts have won!"

```
@objc func updateProgress() {
       if activePlayer == 1 {
           progressBar.progress -= 0.01    
       } else {
           progressBar.progress += 0.01
       }      
}
```

I want to showing 'winner board' when game is over. I added below codes for showing.It is okay. But when i clicked to playAgain button in the first view is hiding but when the second game is over winner board does not hide

```
func endGame() {

timer.invalidate()
gameActive = false
let rect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 500))
rect.tag = 1000
rect.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

self.view.addSubview(rect)
rect.addSubview(gameOverLabel)
rect.addSubview(btnPlayAgain)

gameOverLabel.isHidden = false
btnPlayAgain.isHidden = false

progressBar.progress = 0.5

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{ () -> Void in

    self.gameOverLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.gameOverLabel.center.x + 500, y: self.gameOverLabel.center.y)

    self.btnPlayAgain.center = CGPoint(x: self.btnPlayAgain.center.x + 500, y: self.btnPlayAgain.center.y)

})

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

progressBar.progress = 0.5

gameOverLabel.isHidden = true
gameOverLabel.center = CGPoint(x: gameOverLabel.center.x - 500, y: gameOverLabel.center.y)

btnPlayAgain.isHidden = true
btnPlayAgain.center = CGPoint(x: btnPlayAgain.center.x - 500, y: btnPlayAgain.center.y)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are creating multiple timer scheduled by every clicked. You can try this. First, check the timer code as below:

```
if self.timer.isValid == true {
    self.timer.invalidate()
 }
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.6, target: self, selector: #selector(updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Now, inside your updateProgress, update like this.

```
@objc func updateProgress() {
        if activePlayer == 1 {
            progressBar.progress -= 0.01

        } else {
            progressBar.progress += 0.01
        }

        if progressBar.progress == 1.0 || progressBar.progress == 0.0 {
            if activePlayer == 1 {
                gameOverLabel.text = "Noughts has won!"

            } else {
                gameOverLabel.text = "Crosses has won!"
            }
            endGame()
        }
    }
```